# Фильтрация по дате

Tags: firebird, sql

Добрый день.

Долго бороздил просторы интернета, но ответа на свой вопрос не нашел. Суть вопроса такая: есть отчет по дате и номеру. Дата тип дата. Номер тип строка. Дата представляет собой некий интервал (с... по...). Проблема состоит в том, что когда я оставляю поля контекстных переменных @dateTo и @dateDO пустыми, отчет выводится пустым.

```
t.col_270 >= @dateTo and
t.col_270 <= @dateDo
```

С номером я эту проблему обошел. Сделал номер строкой, и когда номер остается пустой строкой, отчет выводится по всем документам.

```
t.col_329 like '%' || @num || '%'
```

То же мне нужно сделать и по дате. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
t.col_270 >= (CASE WHEN @dateTo IS NOT NULL THEN @dateTo ELSE cast('1990-01-01' as date) END)
and
t.col_270 <= (CASE WHEN @dateDo IS NOT NULL THEN @dateDo ELSE cast('2015-01-01' as date) END)
```

Comment: И вообще, попробуйте выяснить, чему равны ваши переменные, когда вы не задаете их значения.

Comment: И еще попробуйте посмотреть здесь ветвь дискуссий
http://www.firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=coalesce&s[]=null
Возможно вам придется обновить СУБД.

Comment: toxicdream, добрый день. Ваше решение помогло. спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ...
FORM ...
WHERE ((t.col_270 >= @dateTo) OR @dateTo IS NULL) AND
((t.col_270 <= @dateDo) OR @dateDo IS NULL)
```

Comment: renegator, к сожалению, не помогло. так же выходит пустой отчет, когда я оставляю поля пустыми

Comment: Какие поля? t.col_270? Или переменные `@dateTo, @dateDo`? Пустое значение не равно null.

Comment: @renegator, только проверку на NULL стоит поставить перед проверкой даты в строке. По сути, для запроса это константа.

    (ISNULL(@dateTo) OR (t.col_270 >= @dateTo)) AND
    (ISNULL(@dateDo) OR (t.col_270 <= @dateDo))

Comment: Принимается.

Comment: пустое поле в контроле - это чаще всего '', а не NULL.
Поэтому я бы сделал так, "ISNULL(@DateTo, '') = '' or ..."

Comment: >@renegator, к сожалению, не помогло. Так же выходит пустой отчет, когда я оставляю поля пустыми.
Так может нужно начать с того где и чем вы эти самые `@dateTo` и `@dateDo` заполняете?

Answer (score 0):

Ну, легче всего было бы все-таки проверять переменные, прежде чем запрос делать. Подменять `dateTo` нулем, если оно пустое, а `dateDo` - сегодняшней датой. Ибо, как я понимаю, у вас строка юзается как шаблон.

Comment: Grimon, ситуация такая. у меня есть дата составления документа. а @dateTo и @dateDo - это контекстные переменные. я думаю, что стоит сделать некое сравнение этих переменных со значением null, но, так как я только начал осваивать язык sql, у меня это не получается. что-то типа такого хочу:

WHEN @dateTo IS NULL AND @dateDo IS NOT NULL THEN @dateTo = '01.01.1990'
WHEN @dateTo IS NOT NULL AND @dateDo IS NULL THEN @dateDo = '01.01.2015'
WHEN @dateTo IS NULL AND @dateDo IS NULL THEN @dateTo = '01.01.1990' AND @dateDo = '01.01.2015' 

так не работает

Answer (score 0):

Если это MS SQL, то почему бы не использовать ISNULL?

```
 t.col_270 >= ISNULL(@dateTo, '01.01.1990' ) AND t.col_270 <= ISNULL(@dateDo, '01.01.2015')
```

ISNULL сравнивает первое значение с NULL и, если NULL, возвращает второй аргумент (иначе - первый).

Comment: Видимо, я неправильно объяснил суть своей задачи. Или Вы меня неправильно поняли. Мне нужен временной интервал. Например, отчет по датам с... по...

А вообще, в самом процессе, у меня есть только одна дата. Дата заявки. Вот по ней мне и нужно сделать отчет.

Допустим, я задаю с 11.11.2011 по 15.11.2011 и мне выводятся все документы, у которых дата заявки попадает в этот интервал.

Да, еще одно. У меня не MS SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по конкатенации, это не SQL Server. 
Попробуйте такое стандартное решение:

```
t.col_270 between coalesce(@dateTo, '1990-01-01' ) AND coalesce(@dateDo, '2015-01-01')
```

Если неявное преобразование к типу даты работать не будет, то используйте явное преобразование типа 
    cast('1990-01-01' as date)

Comment: msi, у меня возникает ошибка при эмуляции. текст ошибки:
arithmetic exception, numeric overflow, or string truncation string right truncation (арифметическое исключение, числовые переполнения или усечения строки строку сразу усечения (гугл переводчик)).
вопрос такой. как правильно записывать дату? '1990-01-01' или '01.01.1990'. в разных местах по разному написано

Comment: Как ответить на ваш вопрос, если вы шифруетесь? :-)
Какая СУБД?
Какой тип столбца t.col_270?
Какой тип переменной @dateTo?
CAST пробовали типа coalesce(@dateTo, cast('1990-01-01' as date)?
Попробуйте еще так представить дату '19900101'.

Comment: :) я не шифруюсь. СУБД: Firebird. тип колонки: дата/время. тип контекста: дата/время. написал так: 
t.col_270 between coalesce(@dateTo, cast('1990-01-01' as date)) AND coalesce(@dateDo, cast('2015-01-01' as date))
ошибок не было, но отчет по прежнему пустой

Comment: С Firebird не работал. Возможно, тип включает составляющую времени. Что есть тип дата/время? Если бы это была локализованная версия Access, я бы понял. :-) date, datetime или еще что-то? 
Что я бы сделал. 
1) проверил запрос типа
@date = '2011-11-15'
@dateTo = NULL
@dateTo = NULL
select 1 where @date between coalesce(@dateTo, cast('1990-01-01' as date)) AND coalesce(@dateDo, cast('2015-01-01' as date)) 

А вы часом границы не перепутали?
Если работает, то дело в других критериях.

Comment: Возможно, у вас в переменных не NULL, а скажем, пустая строка '', если значение не задано.